# How to redirect all httpErrors to custom url?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, web-config

These are the codes in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" >
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <clear />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/ResourceNotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/ResourceNotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

The above settings will redirect httpError of 404 and 500 only.

But instead of manually add all the error code of 400, 401, 403....etc..etc...

Can we just set it redirect all errors to the same url without typing all the error code?

```
<error statusCode="400" .....
<error statusCode="401" .....
<error statusCode="403" .....
<error statusCode="404" .....
<error statusCode="xxx" ....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this,

add in web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
    path="500.htm" />
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <remove statusCode="401" />
    <error statusCode="401" path="/Account/Login.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <remove statusCode="501"/>
    <error statusCode="501" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <remove statusCode="411"/>
    <error statusCode="411" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <error statusCode="403" path="/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

and more about this http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Comment: The OP asked if there was a way to redirect to an error page for ALL errors without having to enter every possible HTTP error in the web.config. You just re-iterated his question.

Comment: @webworm I picked this as answered as I assumed that he answered the question indirectly. The answer is "No", each http error code has to be defined separately. There is no such thing like error code = <ALL_CODE> :)

Comment: What is the content (source code) of ***Oops.aspx*** ?

Comment: you can add your own page as per your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

The `httpErrors` section has `defaultPath` attribute.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors defaultPath="Error.html" defaultResponseMode="File">
    <clear />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

However, I don't use it, because `defaultPath` is locked in IIS Express by default. Need to edit `%homepath%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config` to unlock it.

```
<httpErrors lockAttributes="allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated,defaultPath">
  <!-- ... -->
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: I made the changes in my IIS Express config file to no avail. Same also with unlocking the IIS installed on my computer. Is there something else that needs to be changed to get the lock issue to go away?

Comment: Modern IIS Express stores config in $(ProjectRoot)\.vs\config directory. Did you edit it?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize it had moved. Editing in the new location did the trick.